# Prepopulate ModelForm fields based on referring URL

Tags: python, django

I have a website which catalogs local hikes. Users can "log" that they have completed these hikes. I have both of these models+forms working as intended. Right now, though, in order to log a hike, you have to select the hike from a long list which contains all the hikes in the database. I'd like to be able to pre-populate that field so that if you are coming from the detail page of the hike in question, then that field is filled in with the hike.

Here's some code:

models.py:

```
model Hike(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    ...other fields...

model UserLog(models.Model):
    hike = models.ForeignKey(Hike, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
class LogHike(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserLog
        fields = ('hike', 'date', ... other fields)
```

views.py:

```
def hike_detail(request, slug):
    hike = Hike.objects.get(slug=slug)
    log = UserLog.objects.filter(hike__slug=slug)
    ... more stuff here ...
    return render(request, 'hikes/hike_detail.html' {
        'hike': hike,
        'log': log,
})

def log_hike(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LogHike(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            userid = request.user
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('user_profile', uid=userid.id)
    else:
        form = LogHike()
    return render(request, 'log_hike.html', {'form': form})
```

So if a user is viewing the "hike_detail" view, I want to have a link that sends them to the "log_hike" view, but with the "Hike" field pre-populated based on the "Hike" that they came from. I think it might have something to do with the instance function? But I don't have a ton of experience with it. Is there an easy way to pass the data from the referring page in order to pre-populate the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-populate that form in `log_hike` when the `request.method` is `get` in the same way as when in `post`.

```
form = LogHike({'hike':hike_id})
```

The other thing is form where you'll take the `hike_id`. But that can come from `request.GET` for example.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I had to set up the referring link as a GET form, and pass the ID that way.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to override your `ModelForm` `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LogHike, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'hike' in kwargs:
        self.fields['hike'].value = kwargs['hike']
```

Now all you need is another view which accepts a parameter passed and you're set. Extend your `urls.py` for that and then do something like:

```
def log_hike_with_pre_set_hike(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # see your code
    else:
        form = LogHike(hike=kwargs['hike'])
    return render(request, 'log_hike.html', {'form': form})
```

Untested code, you might have to adapt it, I come from class-based views so it might be different for you.

Comment: I don't think you have to override the `__init__` method as the first parameter is `data` which is used exactly for what you wan't it to - like when using it for `POST`.

Comment: Other option worked well, but this seems like it would also have done the trick. Thanks for your help!